# Animator.GetFloat returning wrong value unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animator

I have a level with a bunch of AI zombies and that works well enough for now but if instantiate a new prefab zombie of the same type, the new zombie will act the same and set parameters in the animator the same although this is where the problem occurs...

These instantiated AI for what ever reason call the `Animator.GetFloat` function passing the same thing as the other non instantiated AI but this time it will always seem to return `0` and for the life of me I cant figure out why.

Picture one here shows that I am currently using this animation and its setting this parameter to `1` using animation curves which is exactly what I want.

[image: Picture 1]

The problem then comes up in the code. where the call seems to return a wrong value

[image: Picture 2]

UPDATE: Sometimes the first spawned zombie will be able to get that value. idk why

This is what is currently entered in the perameter code and this is the conversion to a hash

[image: Conversion from inspector string to hash]

[image: Inspector View]

My Class that controls the damage to be output when a animator variable is played and player are hit with a collider.

```
public class AIDamageTrigger : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // Inspector Variables
    [SerializeField] string         _parameter = "";
    [SerializeField] int            _bloodParticlesBurstAmount  =   10;
    [SerializeField] float          _damageAmount               =   0.1f;
    [SerializeField] bool           _doDamageSound              =   true;
    [SerializeField] bool           _doPainSound                =   true;

    // Private Variables
    AIStateMachine      _stateMachine       = null;
    Animator            _animator           = null;
    int                 _parameterHash      = -1;
    GameSceneManager    _gameSceneManager   = null;
    private bool        _firstContact       = false;        

    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    // Name :   Start
    // Desc :   Called on object start-up to initialize the script.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    void Start()
    {
        // Cache state machine and animator references
        _stateMachine = transform.root.GetComponentInChildren<AIStateMachine> ();

        if (_stateMachine != null)
            _animator = _stateMachine.animator;

        // Generate parameter hash for more efficient parameter lookups from the animator
        _parameterHash = Animator.StringToHash (_parameter); 

        _gameSceneManager = GameSceneManager.instance;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter( Collider col )
    {
        if (!_animator) 
            return;

        //Debug----------------------
        int leftHandHash = Animator.StringToHash("LeftHand");
        int rightHandHash = Animator.StringToHash("RightHand");
        int mouthHash = Animator.StringToHash("Mouth");
        float left = _animator.GetFloat(leftHandHash);
        float right = _animator.GetFloat(rightHandHash);
        float mouth = _animator.GetFloat(mouthHash);
        //Debug.Log(this.gameObject.transform.parent.transform.parent.transform.parent.transform.parent.transform.transform.parent.parent.transform.parent.transform.parent.transform.parent.name + " : " + left);
        //Debug.Log(this.gameObject.transform.parent.transform.parent.transform.parent.transform.parent.transform.transform.parent.parent.transform.parent.transform.parent.transform.parent.name + " : " + right);
        //Debug.Log(this.gameObject.transform.parent.transform.parent.transform.parent.transform.parent.transform.transform.parent.parent.transform.parent.transform.parent.transform.parent.name + " : " + mouth);
        //----------------------------

        if (col.gameObject.CompareTag ("Player") && _animator.GetFloat(_parameterHash) >0.9f)
             _firstContact = true;
    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    // Name :   OnTriggerStay
    // Desc :   Called by Unity each fixed update that THIS trigger
    //          is in contact with another.
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    void OnTriggerStay( Collider col )
    {
        // If we don't have an animator return
        if (!_animator)
            return;

        int leftHandHash = Animator.StringToHash("LeftHand");
        int rightHandHash = Animator.StringToHash("RightHand");
        int mouthHash = Animator.StringToHash("Mouth");
        float left = _animator.GetFloat(leftHandHash);
        float right = _animator.GetFloat(rightHandHash);
        float mouth = _animator.GetFloat(mouthHash);

        _animator.Update(0);
        // If this is the player object and our parameter is set for damage
        if (col.gameObject.CompareTag ("Player") && _animator.GetFloat(_parameterHash) >0.9f)
        {
            if (GameSceneManager.instance && GameSceneManager.instance.bloodParticles) 
            {
                ParticleSystem system = GameSceneManager.instance.bloodParticles;

                // Temporary Code
                system.transform.position = transform.position;
                system.transform.rotation = Camera.main.transform.rotation;

                var settings = system.main;
                settings.simulationSpace = ParticleSystemSimulationSpace.World;
                system.Emit (_bloodParticlesBurstAmount);
            }

            if (_gameSceneManager!=null)
            {
                PlayerInfo info = _gameSceneManager.GetPlayerInfo( col.GetInstanceID() );
                if (info!=null && info.characterManager!=null)
                {
                    info.characterManager.TakeDamage( _damageAmount, _doDamageSound && _firstContact, _doPainSound );
                }
            }

            _firstContact = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well what is the value of `_parameterHash`? You probably rather wanted to use e.g. `leftHandHash` instead?

Comment: Checking if the animation is done >90% is a very unreliable way if fps differ a lot. I can recommend creating an event (on the last keyframe) which calls a function in your script.

Comment: Ive updated the post and im sorry for missing this piece of information i was very confused at the time and it slipped my mind

Comment: So the way i would like it to work is i would like it to do damage only when the hand contacts the player in the animation which ive placed animation curves for. As im not to experienced what do you think the best way of achieving this is? The animation curves only ever go from 0 to 1 so checking that it is over 0.9 just checks that its not 0 and in the animation the hand is currently making contact

Comment: To be fair it seems to work in the animator just fine but i just cant get the value out for some reason

Comment: @Snake2034 please do not post images of code, rather post your code as text and format it as code (`{ }` button). In general I would **not** recommend using a dynamic field for getting the parameter name. Rather use a `const` and triple check if it is spelled correctly (a trailing ` ` character e.g.). Could it also be a timing issue and you get the value before the `1` is assigned? It would help to see your full code including where and how values get assigned

Comment: Ive posted the class in full so hopefully this helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on your variable `Animator _animator;`

You are doing `_animator = _stateMachine.animator;` and ALL your zombies get the same animator, why you don't use this:

```
_animator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
```

So each zombie get access to its animator.

Comment: I ended up going back a version because i couldnt figure out the problem at the time. Thanks for the help anyway